# Google Stocks API

Tags: api, stocks

I'm developing a bot, and I want to use the Google's Stock's API shown here:

http://jarloo.com/tutorials/google-stock-api/

The only problem is, It was a feature request from someone else and I don't know a lot about stocks.  I see that it is 'undocumented', but does anything have an links to information that I can get what each of the tags from the return is?  A Sample return for yahoo is below.

```
<xml_api_reply version="1">
<finance module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">
<symbol data="YHOO"/>
<pretty_symbol data="YHOO"/>
<symbol_lookup_url data="/finance?client=ig&q=YHOO"/>
<company data="Yahoo! Inc."/>
<exchange data="Nasdaq"/>
<exchange_timezone data="ET"/>
<exchange_utc_offset data="+05:00"/>
<exchange_closing data="960"/>
<divisor data="2"/>
<currency data="USD"/>
<last data="13.59"/>
<high data="13.62"/>
<low data="13.36"/>
<volume data="30493456"/>
<avg_volume data="24328"/>
<market_cap data="17706.97"/>
<open data="13.50"/>
<y_close data="13.48"/>
<change data="+0.11"/>
<perc_change data="0.82"/>
<delay data="0"/>
<trade_timestamp data="6 hours ago"/>
<trade_date_utc data="20110721"/>
<trade_time_utc data="200014"/>
<current_date_utc data="20110722"/>
<current_time_utc data="024141"/>
<symbol_url data="/finance?client=ig&q=YHOO"/>
<chart_url data="/finance/chart?q=NASDAQ:YHOO&tlf=12"/>
<disclaimer_url data="/help/stock_disclaimer.html"/>
<ecn_url data=""/>
<isld_last data="13.60"/>
<isld_trade_date_utc data="20110721"/>
<isld_trade_time_utc data="235853"/>
<brut_last data=""/>
<brut_trade_date_utc data=""/>
<brut_trade_time_utc data=""/>
<daylight_savings data="true"/>
</finance>
</xml_api_reply>
```

Sorry if this isn't exactly a 'programming' question.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Google Finance API is now **deprecated**, I would suggest you to use the Yahoo! Finance API instead:

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=**STOCK_SYMBOLS separated by “+”** &f= **special_tags**

Here is a list of the special tags you may find useful:
http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm